# Impute missing values with the average of the remainder

Tags: r

I have a data frame of the form:

```
Weight  Day     Hour
NA      M       0
NA      M       1
2       M       2
1       M       3
4       T       0
5       T       1
NA      T       2
2       T       3
3       W       0
3       W       1
1       W       2
NA      W       3
```

For a given NA value in **Weight**, I want to replace it with the average of the non-NA values having the same value for **Hour**. For example, the first value in **Weight** is NA. Its **Hour** value is 0, so I want to average the other **Weights** where **Hour** is 0 (those values being 4 and 3). I then want to replace the NA with the computed average (3.5).

As an R beginner, I'd like to see a clear, multistep process for this. (I'm posing this as a learning exercise rather than a specific "solve this problem" type question. I'm not interested in who can do it in the fewest characters.)

Comment: I hope you are aware that there are better methods than mean imputation in most cases.

Comment: @Roland: yes, very aware. This is purely an exercise in learning R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ave` for such operations.

```
dat$Weight <- 
ave(dat$Weight,dat$Hour,FUN=function(x){
  mm <- mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
  ifelse(is.na(x),mm,x)
})
```

- You will apply a function by group of hours.
- For each group you compute the mean wuthout missing values.
- You assign the mean if the value is a missing value otherwise you keep the origin value.
- You replace the Weight vector by the new created vector.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, list(Weight=replace(Weight, is.na(Weight),
       mean(Weight, na.rm=TRUE))),by=Hour]
```

Or

```
setDT(dat)[, Weight1:=mean(Weight, na.rm=TRUE), by=Hour][,
              Weight:=ifelse(is.na(Weight), Weight1, Weight)][, Weight1:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. It is both very fast and easy to understand (because of it's piped structure), thus could be good start for a beginner. Assuming `df` is your data set

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% # Select your data set
  group_by(Hour) %>% # Group by Hour
  mutate(Weight = ifelse(is.na(Weight), 
                         mean(Weight, na.rm = TRUE), 
                         Weight)) # Replace all NAs with the mean
```